# How to "firmly" locate an element in a table? Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, html-table

How can I locate an element "1988" (the fourth line) in the following table:

```
<table border="0" width="820" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td class="default" width="100%">Results <b>1</b> to <b>10</b> of <b>1988</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <td class="default" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">&nbsp;<font class="resultsheader"> ...etc
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

IMPORTANT: I know one way that works (By.xpath):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@width='100%']")).getText();
```

However, this way does not ALWAYS work. The page is dynamic, so I need a way to locate that element no matter what changes happen to the page.
I tried the following but I am not sure:

```
By.xpath("//html//body//table//tbody//tr[3]//td//table//tbody//tr//td[2]//table[4]//tbody//tr[1]//td//b[3]"
```

Comment: If you can affect the HTML code, it is always a good idea to place a class there to keep tests less "brittle". 

If not, perhaps you shall specify what are the dynamic parts of the code - if anything could change, there is no way to write the test, because you don't know what you are looking for.

Comment: @Richard. The problem is that when I locate it using the following method: By.xpath("//td[@width='100%']"...It works (but not always!) because sometimes the page would have other elements that could also be located by the same xpath, and I end up locating the wrong element... **I was hoping to locate this element as a member of that table, which does not change, i.e. the table is static no matter what happens to the page. How can i do this? There should be a way**

Comment: So what's "static" in that table? It seems it isn't, as at least "1988" can change. What _exactly_ is unique in that table which will never occur somewhere else in the page?

Comment: Your selector (the long one) might work (it may select <b>1988</b>) but only if the structure around the table is not very dynamic. Are you able to change the HTML code? If you gave the table a class, you could write a simple, solid selector.

Comment: @Richard  i am not allowed to change html. This table itself is unique on that page, however, the (1988) element's xpath is not unique. So I guess if I specify the table attirbutes, say width="820" cellpadding="2", that would be enough to navigate to that table...but I do not know how to do this... Also how come this does not work: By.xpath("//html//body//table//tbody//tr[3]//td//table//tbody//tr//td[2]//table[4]//tbody//tr[1]//td//b[3]"....Also, is this the right way to navigate an element of the table?

Comment: Your selector may work, but all structural selectors like this are very brittle, slight change in HTML code may break your tests. I'll post the other solution with attributes below where I can format the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the HTML and want to use attributes for selection, you can write something like this:

```
//table[@border=0][@width=820]//tbody//tr[1]//td//b[3]
```

Comment: Why not something simpler like `//td[starts-with(., 'Results')]`?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this syntax, that's certainly useful. Just be sure you are not in multilingual environment, with this sort of selectors the translation may break your test.